# Spartacus service workers disabling

Tags: spartacus-storefront

On production we faced a problem with service worker. We don`t use PWA feature but still have error. Is there way to avoid this?
`ERROR: Service worker registration failed with: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://********') with script ('https://*****/ngsw-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really an Angular question, rather than a Spartacus-specific question.  See the Angular documentation at https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops (particularly the section *Service Worker Safety > Fail-safe*)

Comment: There is no access to angular code with ngsw.json, because its part of Spartacus framework. When we delete it from package.json we have:  ERROR in The target entry-point "@spartacus/storefront" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/service-worker